# Python requests PUT not updating data

Tags: python, python-requests, put

I have a yaml file : `file.yaml` structured as follows :

```
index:
  - uid: "uid"
    name: "name"
    headline: "headline"
    overview: "overview"
    features: "features"
    instructions: "instructions"
    callback_url: "https://some-url.com/params"
    edit_url: "https://edit-url/params"
    uninstall_hook: "https://uninstall-url/params"
    svg: 
    screenshot1: 
    screenshot2: 
    screenshot3:
```

I have to upload those informations to an api endpoint by performing a PUT request. I managed to do it first using the `register.py` following script that I just run `python register.py`:

```
import json
import requests
from pathlib import Path
import base64
import yaml

BASE_URL = "https://url.com"  # API Host
FILE_FOLDER = Path.cwd()  # Current working directory


if __name__ == "__main__":

    public_key = <public_key>
    private_key = <private_key>

    auth_key = "{}:{}".format(public_key, private_key).encode("utf-8")

    encodedKey = base64.b64encode(auth_key).decode("utf-8")

    headers = {"Authorization": f"Basic {encodedKey}", "Content-type": "application/json"}

    def update_app_info():
        infos_file = FILE_FOLDER / "file.yaml"
        with open(infos_file) as infos_file_data:
            yamlcontent = yaml.safe_load(infos_file_data)  # Parse file.yaml and produce a dictionary of it
        file_infos = yamlcontent["index"][0]  # retrieve actual configuration informations
        response = requests.put(
            f"{BASE_URL}/path/to/api_endpoint/{public_key}", data=json.dumps(file_infos), headers=headers
        )
        print(response)
        print(response.json())

    update_app_info()
```

That gives a `202` success response.
As you may observe, I tried to get content of the yaml file as a dicitonary and send that in `data`. I proceeded that way regarding format of data at `GET https://url.com/path/to/api_endpoint` (mock example for illustration...) . Having the dictionary `file_infos` seemed more appropriate and gets me a success response. Sending directly the file itself or '`infos_file_data`' gave me some errors I got over with the above script.

The issue is when I update `svg`, `screenshot1`, `screenshot2` & `screenshot3` so that `file.yaml` is now :

```
index:
  - uid: "uid"
    name: "name"
    headline: "headline"
    overview: "overview"
    features: "features"
    instructions: "instructions"
    callback_url: "https://some-url.com/params"
    edit_url: "https://edit-url/params"
    uninstall_hook: "https://uninstall-url/params"
    svg: "icon.svg"
    screenshot1: "screenshot1.png"
    screenshot2: "screenshot2.png"
    screenshot3: "screenshot3.png"
```

That gives now :

```
<Response [400]>

{'error': {'message': {'svg': ['The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.'], 'screenshot1': ['The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.'], 'screenshot2': ['The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.'], 'screenshot3': ['The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.']}, 'code': 400}}
```

I've done multiple searches ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864021/the-submitted-data-was-not-a-file-check-the-encoding-type-on-the-form-valida) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-request-using-postman/41435972#41435972) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017119/put-request-for-image-upload-not-working-in-django-rest) , [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181299/put-python-requests-is-not-updating-data) , [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447681/cannot-upload-images-using-python-requests)...) but their application and few other errors, eventually get me to this :

```
import base64
import json
from pathlib import Path

import requests
import yaml

from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

BASE_URL = "https://url.com"  # API Host
FILE_FOLDER = Path.cwd()  # Current working directory


if __name__ == "__main__":

    public_key = <public_key>
    private_key = <private_key>

    auth_key = "{}:{}".format(public_key, private_key).encode("utf-8")

    encodedKey = base64.b64encode(auth_key).decode("utf-8")

    def update_app_info():
        infos_file = FILE_FOLDER / "file.yaml"
        with open(infos_file) as infos_file_data:
            yamlcontent = yaml.safe_load(infos_file_data)  # Parse file.yaml and produce a dictionary of it
        file_infos = yamlcontent["index"][0]  # retrieve actual configuration informations
        m = MultipartEncoder(fields=file_infos)
        #print(m.content_type)
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Basic {encodedKey}",
            "Content-Type": m.content_type,
        }

        response = requests.put(
            f"{BASE_URL}/path/to/api_endpoint/{public_key}",
            data=json.dumps(file_infos),
            headers=headers
        )
        print(response)
        print(response.json())

    update_app_info()
```

That is also giving me the `202` success response but the file `svg`, `screenshot1`, `screenshot2` & `screenshot3` fields are not updated.

I'll share more informations where needed. Your help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got [additional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116016/what-is-the-right-way-to-post-multipart-form-data-using-curl) [resources](https://curlconverter.com/) that helped.

As I was trying to solve my issue, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67487414/11209060). It happens I didn't wrote `files` part as it should, plus I was having `data` as a JSON string. That causes a `ValueError: Data must not be a string.` error. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27553321/11209060) was useful to get it fixed.

Now, for what it's worth, here's the working script :

```
import base64
from pathlib import Path

import requests
import yaml


BASE_URL = "https://url.com"  # API Host
FILE_FOLDER = Path.cwd()  # Current working directory


if __name__ == "__main__":

    public_key = <public_key>
    private_key = <private_key>

    auth_key = "{}:{}".format(public_key, private_key).encode("utf-8")
    encodedKey = base64.b64encode(auth_key).decode("utf-8")

    def update_app_info():
        infos_file = FILE_FOLDER / "file.yaml"
        with open(infos_file) as infos_file_data:
            yamlcontent = yaml.safe_load(infos_file_data)  # Parse file.yaml and produce a dictionary of it
        if "index" in yamlcontent:
            file_infos = yamlcontent["index"][0]  # retrieve actual configuration informations
            headers = {
                "Authorization": f"Basic {encodedKey}",
            }
            files = {
                "svg": open("icon.svg", "rb"),
                "screenshot1": open("screenshot1.png", "rb"),
                "screenshot2": open("screenshot2.png", "rb"),
                "screenshot3": open("screenshot3.png", "rb"),
            }
            response = requests.put(
                f"{BASE_URL}/path/to/api_endpoint/{public_key}", data=file_infos, files=files, headers=headers
            )
            print("\n", response)
            print("\n", response.headers)
            print("\n", response.json())

    update_app_info()
```